# Consumer does not work after some idle time (rabbitmq broker)

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring-cloud-stream and rabbitmq binder for some simple testing for use case that I am going to use in future.

Below is the consumer that I am using.

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Flux<Message<RssModel>>> rssConsumer1(RssTaskHandler taskHandler) {
    return flux -> {
        flux.map(s -> s.getPayload()).doOnNext(System.out::println).subscribe();
    };
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        requester1:
          destination: rss-exchange
          group: requester
      function:
        bindings:
          rssConsumer1-in-0: requester1        
        definition: rssConsumer1
```

Model class:

```
public class RssModel {

private String contentcategory;

private String rssfeedurl;

private String channel;

private String contentowner;

public String getContentcategory() {
    return contentcategory;
}

public void setContentcategory(String contentcategory) {
    this.contentcategory = contentcategory;
}

public String getRssfeedurl() {
    return rssfeedurl;
}

public void setRssfeedurl(String rssfeedurl) {
    this.rssfeedurl = rssfeedurl;
}

public String getChannel() {
    return channel;
}

public void setChannel(String channel) {
    this.channel = channel;
}

public String getContentowner() {
    return contentowner;
}

public void setContentowner(String contentowner) {
    this.contentowner = contentowner;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RssModel [contentcategory=" + contentcategory + ", rssfeedurl=" + rssfeedurl + ", channel=" + channel
            + ", contentowner=" + contentowner + "]";
}
```

}

Payload that I am sending from GUI of rabbitmq on the queue:

```
{"contentCategory": "", "rssFeedUrl": "http://somevalidrssurl/rss.xml","channel": "016179", "contentOwner": "RTES"}
```

Here everthing works and I am getting model that is being sent from the rabbit-mq in output.

**Problem**
After some idle time I am getting below exception:

```
 2021-09-16 18:11:32.575 ERROR 19732 --- [nge.requester-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'worker-stream.requester1'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[151], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=rss-exchange.requester, amqp_receivedExchange=, amqp_deliveryTag=3, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=rss-exchange.requester, amqp_redelivered=false, id=dd6addcb-4b18-c853-6f96-8e7af8d953a4, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-dYcS5GwSXV5qrqZtcIF29A, sourceData=(Body:'[B@222405ac(byte[151])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=rss-exchange.requester, deliveryTag=3, consumerTag=amq.ctag-dYcS5GwSXV5qrqZtcIF29A, consumerQueue=rss-exchange.requester]), contentType=application/json, timestamp=1631796089561}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[151], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=rss-exchange.requester, amqp_receivedExchange=, amqp_deliveryTag=3, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=rss-exchange.requester, amqp_redelivered=false, id=dd6addcb-4b18-c853-6f96-8e7af8d953a4, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-dYcS5GwSXV5qrqZtcIF29A, sourceData=(Body:'[B@222405ac(byte[151])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=rss-exchange.requester, deliveryTag=3, consumerTag=amq.ctag-dYcS5GwSXV5qrqZtcIF29A, consumerQueue=rss-exchange.requester]), contentType=application/json, timestamp=1631796089561}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1300(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:308)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:304)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1632)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1551)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1539)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1530)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:967)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1194)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[151], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=rss-exchange.requester, amqp_receivedExchange=, amqp_deliveryTag=3, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=rss-exchange.requester, amqp_redelivered=false, id=dd6addcb-4b18-c853-6f96-8e7af8d953a4, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-dYcS5GwSXV5qrqZtcIF29A, sourceData=(Body:'[B@222405ac(byte[151])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=rss-exchange.requester, deliveryTag=3, consumerTag=amq.ctag-dYcS5GwSXV5qrqZtcIF29A, consumerQueue=rss-exchange.requester]), contentType=application/json, timestamp=1631796089561}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    ... 23 more
```

Post this the consumer stops and does not receive any message but throw the same exception.

I am pretty sure that it has something to do with reactive in consumer. Since none-reactive consumer does not have this problem.

Comment: This is quite strange and the provided stack trace is kind of an after-the-fact error. Something happened before that that completed the subscription. I don't know what that may be as I have no way of reproducing it. Can you create a bare-minimum project that reproduces it and push it to Github so we can take a look?

Comment: Sure @OlegZhurakousky. Will share the project once built.

Comment: Hello @OlegZhurakousky, project is added at  GitHub location "github.com/Mhsh/spring-cloud-stream-reactive-app.git">
Also, I think I narrowed down the problem. 
1) Start the application and send the valid JSON that is mentioned in the above question.
2) This works all the time
3) Pass some wrong payload (some invalid JSON text). Here some exceptions will occur mostly class cast or something.
4) Now try to pass valid JSON it will reproduce the above-mentioned problem.

So idle program is not the cause it seems but an exception in-stream causes the above behavior that is what I believe.

Comment: Hi @OlegZhurakousky. did you get a chance to look at the problem?